# ¿Cómo se explica el origen de «mojigato»?

Tags: etimología, vocabulario

El DLE indica que [**mojigato**](http://dle.rae.es/?id=PXaVM1m) es:

> De *mojo*, voz para llamar al gato, y *gato<sup>1</sup>*
>   1. adj. Que muestra exagerados escrúpulos morales o religiosos. U. t. c. s. U. m. en sent. despect.
>   2. adj. Propio de la persona mojigata. U. m. en sent. despect.
>   3. adj. p. us. Que afecta humildad o cobardía para lograr sus propósitos. U. t. c. s. U. m. en sent. despect.

No veo ninguna relación entre la etimología indicada (voz para llamar al gato + gato) y las acepciones de la palabra. ¿Cómo se puede explicar a partir de ese origen (si es correcto) las acepciones de la palabra?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ya en ocasiones anteriores hemos visto que Sebastián de Covarrubias a veces se inventaba un poco las etimologías de las palabras, pero no por eso debemos dejar de constar aquí la primera explicación que se le da al origen de esta palabra, en su diccionario de 1611:

> MOXIGATO, se dice del hombre, que està muy dissimulado y callado, humilde, esperando la ocasion para hazer su hecho, como haze el gato quãdo està esperando a que salga el raton: demanera que està compuesto de mus, que vale raton, y de gato, con esta alusion y similitud.

El diccionario de autoridades (tomo G-M de 1734) recoge la palabra como:

> MOGIGATO, TA. adj, Dissimulado, que afecta humildad o cobardía, para lograr su intento en la ocasión. Según Covarr. se dijo por alusion ò semejanza al gato, quando está esperando al ratón, y dice que es voz compuesta de Mus, Latino que significa el ratón, y la voz Gato.

Es cierto que las primeras ediciones del DLE no cuestionaban mucho las etimologías de Covarrubias. Sin embargo, desde su segunda edición hasta la de 1884 se suprimieron las etimologías. Cuando volvieron, la primera tentativa es decir que *mojigato* viene de *mogato* (1884). Luego que viene del árabe *motagatta*, "encubierto" (1899). Luego omite la etimología hasta 1970, en la que dice que viene "de la voz *moch*, de llamar al gato, y *gato*", que es básicamente lo que dice hoy día.

Si seguimos la pista de *mogate*, Covarrubias dice:

> MOGATE, es nombre Arabigo, y sinifica cobertura, o baño que cubre alguna cosa [...]. Su raiz es mugati, que en Arabigo vale cubierto, o disimulado: y de alli llamaron Mogatos y moxigatos a los dissimulados.

Es decir, de nuevo volveríamos al árabe y a la etimología que explica que viene de "disimulado, encubierto". Sin embargo, debemos recordar que hoy día esa etimología parece descartada, y la acercan mucho a la palabra *gatamuso* (o *gatomuso*):

> **[gatomuso, sa](http://dle.rae.es/?id=J0XMNHw)**
>
> De *gato<sup>1</sup>* y *muso*, voz con que se llama a este animal.
>
> 1. adj. Vall. Hipócrita, solapado. U. t. c. s.

Aunque la palabra se usa únicamente en Valladolid (España), el significado es similar al original de la palabra *mojigato* (la acepción relativa a los escrúpulos morales o religiosos es bastante posterior).

La combinación de palabras como *muso*, *misi* y similares con el sustantivo *gato* no era infrecuente, de hecho aparece en una canción infantil de la cual he leído y oído diferentes versiones, pero he aquí una:

> Misi gatito,
>   pan con ajito,
>   sopita de la olla,
>   agüita del río
>   si no quieres que te coma topa topa topa
>   *(se hacen cosquillitas en la mejilla del bebé)*

Ese "misi gatito" sería la forma de llamar al gato, y lo mismo sería *misigato* o *moxigato* según la región. Cuando llamas a un gato es porque suele estar escondido, oculto, y de los gatos siempre se ha pensado que son zaínos, taimados, astutos, y cuyas intenciones no siempre son claras. De ahí la asociación de esa personalidad gatuna a las personas que se comportan de forma similar.

Comment: @JamesBolivar no he encontrado nada definitivo. Por ejemplo, vi un texto con la palabra "monjigato" que no sé si sería un juego de palabras con "monja" o un error ortográfico. Imagino que en el caso de la acepción 1 entraría en juego el que la escrupulosidad moral o religiosa podría ser una fachada que oculta otros secretos (lo que suelen decir de que "los calladitos son los peores"). Podría ser que los propósitos ocultos de la acepción 3 fuesen disimulados con esta fachada de beato y a partir de ahí se llamara _mojigato_ simplemente a los que exhiben dicha fachada.